# Why does this form of piecewise function cause a general stop message?

Tags: recursion, piecewise

I am currently learning about *Mathematica* by reading the book *Mathematica* by Example, 4th Edition.

In that book, a piecewise function was defined as follows:

```
s[t_]:= 1/;0<= t <1
s[t_]:=1 + s[t-1]/; t>=1
```

I thought I can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> pw <kbd>Esc</kbd> to define the same function as above. However, when i do that, *Mathematica* crashes and I receive a few messages about exceeding the recursion depth. I basically typed this into the cell:

$$
s[t\_]=\begin{cases}
1 & \quad0\leq t<1\\
1+s[t-1] & \quad t\geq1
\end{cases}
$$

And received many messages about exceeding a recursion depth, then *Mathematica* crashes.

Here's a screenshot of what I did and the messages I received:
[image]

Why does this happen and what is the correct way to use the shortcut to define the above `Piecewise` function?

Comment: Try using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`: `s[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= t < 1}, {1 + s[t - 1], t >= 1}}]`.